# NSNumberFormatter thousand separator and trailing zeros

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I have an object in my account array with a value of 8500.00. I'd like to display that as 8,500.00 but when I try to do so and print to the console it returns null. Any ideas?

App Delegate

```
NSArray *balance        = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"120.50", @"8500.00", nil];
```

// View controller

```
// Setup number formatter
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSNumber *balance = [[appDelegate.accounts objectForKey:@"Available Balance"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"%@", balance); // Prints 8500.00

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:balance]); // Prints null
```

Comment: show us how you added the objects to `accounts`. I assume they aren't NSNumber instances.

Comment: NSNumber *balance = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:8500.00]; line works well for me. vikingosegundo is right, Please check with NSNumber instance.

Comment: // Setup number formatter
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

NSNumber *balance = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[[appDelegate.accounts objectForKey:@"Available Balance"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatvalue]];
NSLog(@"%@", balance); // Prints 8500.00

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:balance]); // Prints null

Comment: @VinayBagale please use pastie.org if you really need to paste your code in comments

Comment: @VinayBagale that returns 8,500. I've already managed to get this value. It seems to be dropping the two trailing zeros. I'd like to get this value 8,500.00

Comment: you `balance` holds `NSString` instances not `NSNumber` ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array balance is an array of `NSString` NOT `NSNumber`s. That's why method `stringFromNumber:` returns nil.

The following example works fine:

```
NSArray *balanceArr =@[@(120.50), @(8500.00)];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setGroupingSize:3];
[formatter setGroupingSeparator:@"'"];
for (NSNumber *balance in balanceArr) {
    NSLog(@"Straight printing: %@", balance);
    NSLog(@"NumberFormatter: %@", [formatter stringFromNumber:balance]);
}
```

Output:

```
2014-08-22 12:18:16.669 dsghdtu[5343:60b] Straight printing: 120.5
2014-08-22 12:18:16.671 dsghdtu[5343:60b] NumberFormatter: 120.50
2014-08-22 12:18:16.671 dsghdtu[5343:60b] Straight printing: 8500
2014-08-22 12:18:16.672 dsghdtu[5343:60b] NumberFormatter: 8'500.00
```

Comment: I want it to be printing 120.50

Comment: That's not a big problem. Please look at my modified answer (you can also use NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle to setup fractionDigits)